# Bundling Python script to run on different Macs

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I wrote a Python script that scrapes PDFs that are in the same directory as the file itself.

I used pyinstaller on my Mac to convert this to a onefile .exe on my MacBook Pro and it works great. However, when I try to send this file to someone else via email, it doesn't open because "it's a Windows file", despite the fact that it was compiled/bundled on a Mac. The modules I use are regex, PyPDF2, among other non-standard libraries. How do I make these executables run on different computers?

I've tried using auto-py-to-exe, but to no avail.

The executables work as built on my Mac, but when I email it to someone whose Mac does not have Python/IDLE installed, I run into a wall. If it makes a difference, I've made a version for Windows, and that works great, too.

Comment: you can use docker for this

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to compile Python programs separately for each environment. If you're on Linux, give [crossenv](https://pypi.org/project/crossenv/) a try.

If you aren't on Linux, to build packages that work on a Mac without IDLE installed, try [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

You can also suggest that whoever you're sending this file to install [wine](https://www.winehq.org/), which will let them run the .exe (though installing python might be a tad easier for them.)